# SSH tunneling in an airport

Tags: ssh, proxy

being at home, I know how to establish ssh tunnels between the work gateway. The main thing is for the gateway, to be able to establish a ssh connection with my machine at home. I do this setting the NAT options of the wifi router.

But sometimes I am at the airport. Here, the wifi connection does not allow to establish this kind of connections.

Do you know any other way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you can't connect because the airport has a firewall that is filtering outbound ports. If you have your ssh daemon listen on TCP port 80 (reserved for HTTP) or 443 (reserved for HTTP/S) it would probably work.

Comment: Right. It covers my now deleted answer. I missed "my machine at home" part of the question. Did not recommended port 80/443 change because I assumed a server, in which does ports are already in use. One up :-)

Comment: I recommend more HTTPS because HTTP won't work if they have a web proxy which is very likely.

Answer (score 0):

You could configure your ssh server at home to listen at port 80, which should be open from the airport wifi network.

If they route the web traffic through their own proxy server there are projects to tunnel ssh through a http proxy like this one:

[Corkscrew](http://www.mtu.net/~engstrom/ssh-proxy.php)